# plot count values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a function that finds the correct and mistaken results of tests of four persons. i.e in each run correct has 4 entries same as mistaken.

the test will be performed 10 times. This should be obvious from the answer of corrects.

I want to graphically represent the performance or progress of 1 student.

hope I am clear now.
example:

```
 run = 1     correct = 5     mistake=5  
 .
 .
 .
 run = n     correct = 3     mistake=7
```

my question is how to represent my results graphically?
need to see a graphical representation of the counts of correct and mistake for n runs.

I tried plot and histogram  but they are not a good representation

Not pro in Matlab can you suggest pls.

example: for 10 runs:

```
 corrects = 

[1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4   double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]
```

I did: 
   figure(5);
    bar([mistakes{1}; corrects{1}]);
[image: these are the four values of 4 persons in the first test]

but what i need is the 10 test of person 1

I tried :

```
 bar([mistakes{test}(1) ; corrects{test}(1)]);
```

[image: weird!]
these are not good presentations

Comment: Please refine the phrase 'how to plot correct mistaken results', I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: What would be a "good presentation"? Please describe your problem (I mean general problem) in more details. What is this analysis about? What do you want to illustrate?

Comment: `cell2mat` will be helpful, to get everything into a 2-D array (indexed by test and person).  Then you can grab all tests for person 1 like `correct_mat(:, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd calculate misclassification rate for each run.

Let's say you have vector `run = 1:n;` and `correct = randi(11,1,n)-1;`. Then `mistake = 10 - correct;`.

Misclassification rate would be `MCR = mistake./10;`.

You can plot distribution of as a boxplot:

```
boxplot(MCR)
```

The important thing would be compare MCR distribution between runs with different parameters. So you will have groups of runs and you can separate them on `boxplot`.

In addition, you can plot real MCR values istead of their quantiles on boxplot. See my question on how to do [beeswarm plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9777592/).

**EDIT**:

If your correct results depends on some score you can generate so called **ROC** (Receiver operating characteristic) curve. At this points I would refer you to a [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). Check if it's what you want.

Comment: I meant to plot mistake/total. But you can do correct/total too. Can call it negative rate and positive rate.

Answer (score 0):

So, to compare correct vs wrong for all n runs:

```
correct = zeros(n, 1);
wrong = zeros(n, 1);
for run=1:n
  [correct(run), wrong(run)] = your_function();
end
bar([correct wrong]);
```

So, you store correct/wrong for each run in the arrays. correct(1) will be the number correct on the first run, etc.. bar([correct wrong]); will display two bars for each run - the blue bar for correct and the red bar for wrong.

Comment: thanks @Richante.this will give all as bar how to know which is which can we color? Also this is for 1 run how to see n runs?